# Ext js coding standards/ best practice

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Can anyone share ext js coding standards? Is it worth enough to have two versions of js files - one during development and another compressed version for production environment?

Also can any one suggest on the number of JS files we can have. I read some where that js files gets downloaded serially and hence avoid adding new files just for the sake of readability. Rather to have the contents in minimal number of files. Is this true ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.. you should have 2 versions of your JS.. one is the debug version which should be used during development, and the minified version of the file which should be used for the production environment. 
The reason why a minified version should be used is that file size of a minified version is much smaller than the debug version, hence gets downloaded faster at the client side. Try obfuscation too.. that reduces the size even further, but may sometimes introduce some errors, since obfuscation is pretty difficult to achieve. The YUI Compressor does a pretty good job of it. The smaller the size of your JSes, the faster your website will be ready for use.

When your JSes are included in the `head` of your page, then they are downloaded serially. So to avoid this, put them inside the `body` part of your page. That allows for multiple connections, hence you can download several files simultaneously. Check out [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) page for more such tips.

As for ExtJs, write as many custom components as you can. Extend the built in classes to suit your needs. There are several examples included in the Ext JS package that is available for download. If you need further help, check out the extjs/example/ux folder for Ext JS approved custom components that are shipped along with the Ext JS distribution. 
Avoid using `id`'s in your components.. instead try using `itemId` or `ref` for accessing the components.

Comment: Thanks dude.. the link really helped. It will be useful for any web application development.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the architecture of complex official examples.
The best way - to write their own components based on the built-in.
For ExtJS4 new MVC architecture is well described in the official API-docs.

Two versions of .js (debug and production) should be for any choice.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are asking all this about Ext JS 3, I strongly suggest switching to Ext JS 4 where combining and compressing all your JavaScript files will be a whole lot easier, as there is a special tool for it. Given that you are asking this now, there can't be too many JavaScript files to convert over.

Answer (score 1):

Also try building the custom version for ext-all.js. It saves a lot of download time by reducing the file size. I am sure you wont be using the entire file for your page.

I would also suggest you to implement prime cahce concept so that all the JS/CSS files are downloaded on login page itself. This will make the remaining pages to load faster.

And for your question on serial download, Yes. Each js download is a HTTP request and it happens serially. So try to have JS files downloaded in the body, if it is not really required on page load.